# LINQ:How to flatten deep nested objects with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to flatten that model into collection.

```
public class Category 
  {
      public string name;   
      public  string id;          
      public  Subcategory subcategory;
  }


public class Subcategory
{
   public string name;   
   public  string id;          
   public List<Product> products;
}


public class Product
{
   public string name;   
   public  string id;          
   public Supplier1 supplier1;
   public Supplier2 supplier2
}

public class Supplier1 
{
   public string name;   
   public  string id;          

}
public class Supplier2 
{
   public string name;   
   public  string id;          

}
```

I need to use LINQ to turn them into a collection of objects of the following type:

```
public class MixedClass 
 {
  public string  CategoryId;   
  public string  SubcategoryId;          
  public string  ProductId ;
  public string  Supplier1Id ;
  public string  Supplier2Id ;

 }
```

I've tried selectmany but I couldn't go deep enough.

Comment: Can you post your failed attempt? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. How do these classes compose together?

Comment: How are you expecting us to get the ProductId? There's **more than one** `Product`. That's why it's in a `List<Product>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
var results = 
    from c in Categories
    from p in c.subcategory.products
    select new MixedClass()
    {
        CategoryId = c.id,
        SubcategoryId = c.subcategory.id,
        ProductId = p.id,
        Supplier1Id = p.supplier1.id,
        Supplier2Id = p.supplier2.id,
    };
```

Or if you prefer fluent syntax:

```
var results = Categories
    .SelectMany(c => c.subcategory.products, 
                (c, p) => new MixedClass()
                {
                    CategoryId = c.id,
                    SubcategoryId = c.subcategory.id,
                    ProductId = p.id,
                    Supplier1Id = p.supplier1.id,
                    Supplier2Id = p.supplier2.id,
                });
```

Comment: Second version gives me error regarding "x" as unknown, where does it come from?
However first version is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @user2373759 Oops, I had written it one way (with an `x`), then changed it - but left that part in. I've corrected it.